# Getting JSON VALUE in mySQL using android

Tags: android, json

I have a problem getting a json value in PHP(mySQL). How can i get the value of **totaly** in the php page. I just want the value of totaly. Please help me. I am newbie in android programming.

This is my php page.

```
    {"sales":[{"pid":"1","name":"book of eden","number_to_sale":"2","price":"2.00","total":"4.00","created_at":"2014-02-02 11:31:53"},{"pid":"2","name":"shirt","number_to_sale":"2","price":"500.00","total":"1000.00","created_at":"2014-02-03 14:23:49"},{"pid":"3","name":"mars","number_to_sale":"2","price":"2.00","total":"4.00","created_at":"2014-02-03 21:07:48"},{"pid":"4","name":"shirt","number_to_sale":"1","price":"500.00","total":"500.00","created_at":"2014-02-07 12:05:18"},{"pid":"5","name":"item2","number_to_sale":"4","price":"400.00","total":"1600.00","created_at":"2014-02-12 13:57:49"},{"pid":"6","name":"shirt","number_to_sale":"2","price":"500.00","total":"1000.00","created_at":"2014-02-12 15:42:04"}],"success":1}

[{"totaly":"4108.00"}]
```

and this is my activity in android

```
    package com.sales;


public class AllSalesActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    AdminJSONParser jParser = new AdminJSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> salesList;


    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/android_supplyinfo/sales/get_all_sales.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_SALES = "sales";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_DATE= "created_at";
    private static final String TAG_TOTAL_ALL= "totaly";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray sales = null;
    JSONArray wtf = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sales_all);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        salesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditSalesActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

        Button btnBacktoMain = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBackMain);
        btnBacktoMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);   
            }
        });



    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received 
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllSalesActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading sales. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    sales = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SALES);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < sales.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = sales.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        salesList.add(map);


                    }

                    JSONArray wtf = new JSONArray("");
                    for (int i = 0; i < wtf.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject total = wtf.getJSONObject(i);



                    TextView txtTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_all);
                    txtTotal.setText(total.getString(TAG_TOTAL_ALL));
                    }

                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        //  AddSalesActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    //startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllSalesActivity.this, salesList,
                            R.layout.sales_list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,TAG_NAME,TAG_DATE},new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.date });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on JSON-objects, but it seems to me that the php page is not returning the "totaly" part inside your JSON-object. If it instead returned it like this:

```
{"sales":[{"pid":"1","name":"book of eden","number_to_sale":"2","price":"2.00","total":"4.00","created_at":"2014-02-02 11:31:53"},{"pid":"2","name":"shirt","number_to_sale":"2","price":"500.00","total":"1000.00","created_at":"2014-02-03 14:23:49"},{"pid":"3","name":"mars","number_to_sale":"2","price":"2.00","total":"4.00","created_at":"2014-02-03 21:07:48"},{"pid":"4","name":"shirt","number_to_sale":"1","price":"500.00","total":"500.00","created_at":"2014-02-07 12:05:18"},{"pid":"5","name":"item2","number_to_sale":"4","price":"400.00","total":"1600.00","created_at":"2014-02-12 13:57:49"},{"pid":"6","name":"shirt","number_to_sale":"2","price":"500.00","total":"1000.00","created_at":"2014-02-12 15:42:04"}],"success":1, "totaly":"4108.00"}
```

Then you could get the "totaly" part like your "success":

```
int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
String totaly = json.getString(TAG_TOTAL_ALL);
```